# Formik API : send different value in handleSubmit based on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have the following code of a child component which is sending the form values to the parent when a user clicks .

1. `Save and Continue` button
2. `Submit` button

The `Save and Continue` button in the code is defined as follows:

```
<div className="form-field">
     <Button size="large" variant="contained" color="primary"  style={{marginLeft: '5px'}} type="submit">Save & Continue</Button>
 </div>
```

When a user clicks `Save and Continue` button, I want to return   `requestStatuses: props.SimpleRequest && props.SimpleRequest.statusId || '10',`.

However, when  a user clicks the following `Submit` button:

```
 <Button size="large" variant="contained" color="primary"
                            type="submit">Submit</Button>
```

I want to return `props.SimpleRequest && props.SimpleRequest.statusId || '6',`.

The default value for Status is `6` when a user interacts with the form and the dropdown is disabled so user can't change it. However, I want to send different values of it as I explained above based on different button clicks. Is it possible?

**Minimal Code with relavent Formik form information is below:**

```
 const SimpleRequestForm = (props) => {

const {values, setFieldValue, touched, errors, isSubmitting, handleReset, handleChange} = 
 props;
const growl = React.createRef()


return (
    <div>
       
        <div id="formDiv">
            <Growl ref={growl}/>
            <Form className="form-column-3">
            <div className="SimpleRequest-form">                    
                        

                        <div className="form-field">
                            <CustomSelectField name="requestStatuses" disabled type="select"  placeholder="Status"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-field">
                            <CustomSelectField name="requestPrioritieses" type="select" value='Normal'  placeholder="Priority"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-field">
                            <CustomSelectField name="assignees" type="select"  placeholder="Assignee"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-field">
                            <Button size="large" variant="contained" color="primary"  style={{marginLeft: '5px'}} type="submit">Save & Continue</Button>
                        </div>
                        
                </div>


                <div className="btn-group-right">
                    <Button size="large" variant="contained" color="primary"
                            type="submit">Submit</Button>
                    <Button size="large" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleReset}
                            style={{marginLeft: '5px'}} type="button">Reset</Button>
                    <Button size="large" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={props.onCancel}
                            style={{marginLeft: '5px'}} type="button">Cancel</Button>       
                  
                   
                </div>
            </Form>
        </div>
    </div>
)

 };

 export const SimpleRequestEnhancedForm = withFormik(



{

    
mapPropsToValues: props => {

          
    
    return {
        requestId: props.SimpleRequest && props.SimpleRequest.requestId || '',
        requestStatuses: props.SimpleRequest && props.SimpleRequest.statusId || '6',
        requestPrioritieses: props.SimpleRequest && props.SimpleRequest.priorityId || '3',
        assignees: props.SimpleRequest && props.SimpleRequest.assigneeId || '',
                 
    }
},
validationSchema:validationSchema,
handleSubmit(values, {props, resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting}) {
    console.log("submit Simple Request Form....")
    values.assets = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('uploadedFiles'));
    props.handleSubmit(values)
    setSubmitting(false)
},
setFieldValue(field, value, shouldVal) {
    console.log('In setFieldValue')
},

displayName: 'Simple Request Form',
  })(SimpleRequestForm)
```

Comment: Instead of a `type=submit` button, you can use an `onClick` event handler and call Formik's `submitForm`.

Comment: ` call Formik's submitForm` I'm not clear on this. Inside `onClick` even handler, could you elaborate on how to call `submitForm` based on my context? Thanks !